# Is the theory $\Sigma$ in the Gödel's paper on the consistency of the generalized continuum hypothesis stronger than $ZF$?

Tags: set-theory

In Kurt Gödel's [article](https://ia800701.us.archive.org/11/items/KurtGdelCollectedWorksVolumeIII1995/Kurt_G%C3%B6del_Collected_Works_Volume_II_1989.pdf#page=51) "the consistency of the axiom of choice and of the generalized continuum-hypothesis" 1940 edition, the working theory $\Sigma$ has a Replacement axiom (p. 38 in the link [1](https://ia800701.us.archive.org/11/items/KurtGdelCollectedWorksVolumeIII1995/Kurt_G%C3%B6del_Collected_Works_Volume_II_1989.pdf#page=51), axiom C4). This axiom seems stronger than Fraenkel's Replacement schema, because it is not limited to the definable functions, and applies instead to all class functions, making $\Sigma$ finitely axiomatizable. Does this make $\Sigma$ much stronger than $ZF$?

I don't think that $\Sigma$ is not *less* powerful that $ZF$, so then I would expect $Con(\Sigma)$ be a stronger statement than $Con(ZF)$. The main result of the article is $Con(\Sigma) \rightarrow Con(\Sigma + GHC)$, but I want to be sure that $GHC$ is relatively consistent with $ZF$, i. e. $Con(ZF) \rightarrow Con(ZF + GHC)$. For me, this doesn't immediately follow, because the antecedent in the latter statement is weaker. Can we derive $Con(ZF) \rightarrow Con(ZF + GHC)$ from the theorem in the article, or do we need to do the whole construction from scratch if we want to get this result for $ZF$?

Also is $\Sigma$ actually stronger than $ZF$ or is it just a superficial difference that doesn't lead to any new theorems?

Comment: Without looking, I'm going to guess this was a formulation of the von Neumann–Gödel–Bernays system which has a 2nd order flavour to it.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila you're right. Now that you've given me the right keyword to search for, I've found all the answers on wikipedia. Not sure if I need to flag the question to be closed or if it can help someone else find the official name of the theory too

Comment: @JohnDoe: I've been studying set theory for over a decade now. I *know* that NBG is not a second-order theory. It is, however, equivalent to the 2nd-order Henkinsation of ZFC. Which is why we often say that it is a second-order set theory. I understood the question just fine, thank you.

Comment: @Nikita:  The paper you're talking about is the one where Gödel introduces constructible sets, the constructible universe $L$ and shows it has a global well-ordering and GCH.  If it bothers you that Gödel does all this in NBG and you doubt it can be done in ZF, it's done in ZF in Jech's books Axiom of Choice and Set Theory.